# Angular2 order JSON data by field

Tags: json, angular, pipe, pipes-filters

I'm currently display JSON data on my angular2 app that I'm getting from my service via the backend, the html looks like this:

```
<tbody *ngFor=" let user of users | sort: 'points'">
                <td> {{user.id}} </td>
                <td> {{user.name}} </td>
                <td> {{user.points}} </td>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to display this data in descending order based on the points field, so the user with the highest amount of points will be displayed first.

Here is my sort pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {
array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if ( a[args] < b[args] ){
        return -1;
    }else if( a[args] > b[args] ){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;   
    }
});
return array;
 }
}
```

I have imported the pipe in app.module.ts and added it to declarations, but getting an error when trying to load the data:

```
Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing the error because there are no values . Just check if the array has values inside your pipe as follows,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {
        if(!array)
        {
            return [];
        }
        if (array & array.length > 0) {
            array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                if (a[args] < b[args]) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (a[args] > b[args]) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });
            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your users are initialized before trying to render the table. try this:

```
<table *ngIf="users">
     <tbody *ngFor=" let user of users | sort: 'points'">
            <td> {{user.id}} </td>
            <td> {{user.name}} </td>
            <td> {{user.points}} </td>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Otherwise your pipe looks like ti should work.

As an aside, the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) recommends not sorting in pipes. They say its not very efficient and you'd have better code if you sorted in the component itself.